# Telerik problems with IntelliSense and Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, intellisense, data-annotations, telerik-mvc

I am working on the project where I use Telerik MVC controls in order to show some NumericTextBoxes and other controls. I have two problems that are maybe related.

1/ IntelliSense works fine in Views/Shared and in some Views. But in some it doesn´t work. The code is absolutely similar without specific blocks of code. I try to add all Telerik namespaces to Web.Config in Views folder, but it doesn´t work. Just in Views/Shared is IntelliSense working.

2/ I would like to use [SourceCodeFile] attribute in my Controller in order to using NumericTextBoxes templates. But VS says "Unknown attribute" and "Resolve" is not in context menu. I was trying to add all Telerik namespaces but it still doesn´t work.

Some suggestions?